# Database query not working when field is queried as a string

Tags: database

I'm not sure if this is a Drupal issue or a SQL issue but here I go.

I have a database table storing addresses. The schema of the relevant fields look like this:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| address        | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| address_number | varchar(7)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have a page with a search form that searches this table

The problem: whenever I query my table the address_number field is not working. It doesn't show any results for the address_number field.

I called `__toString()` on my query and I narrowed down my problem to this:

When address_number is queried as a string, it doesn't work. i.e. `WHERE address_number = '1600'` returns no results.
However when queried as a number it does return results. i.e. `WHERE address_number = 1600` does work.

How do I change my Drupal database query to make this function properly?

Here is a simplified version of my query:

```
  $fields = array( //This is simplified, there are more fields
    'address',
    'address_number',
  );
  $query = db_select('MY_TABLE_NAME', 'p')
    ->fields('p', $fields)
    ->extend('PagerDefault');
  $query->condition('address_number', $address_number));
  $query->condition('address', '%' . $address . '%', 'LIKE'));
  // Repeat for other fields
  $result = $query
    ->limit(50)
    ->orderBy('p.PRIMARY_KEY')
    ->execute();
  return $result;
```

Comment: If you run your broken query manually (outside of Drupal) what happens? Does it still act like your string column is an integer?

Comment: Yes. It only returns results from the address_number field if I query it as a number i.e. `WHERE address_number = 1600`

Comment: That's an issue with your database server then, not Drupal. You'll have a much better chance of getting an answer if you ask this somewhere for general programming questions like Stack Overflow

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if here or somewhere else was best. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

So I did not figure out why this behavior was happening, I did however figure out how to fix it.

In the upload function for inserting data into this table I cast the address_number to an int and now the query works even if the address_number is a string or an int. i.e `WHERE address_number = '1600'` or `WHERE address_number = '1600'` both work.